# Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement phone auth using firebase.
I was going through this guide -> https://fireship.io/lessons/firebase-phone-authentication-with-angular-4-tutorial/

```
Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined<
    at PhoneLoginComponent.ngOnInit (phone-login.component.ts:41)
    at callHook (core.js:2922)
    at callHooks (core.js:2892)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2844)
    at refreshView (core.js:7213)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8289)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8335)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6991)
    at refreshView (core.js:7248)
```

I keep getting the above error

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.windowRef = this.win.windowRef;
   this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new  auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
   this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.render();
}
```

I have already initialized firebase app in app.module.ts

from package.json
"firebase": "^7.15.5"
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Answer (score 2):

First solution
Try this import

```
import { auth } from 'firebase';
```

Second solution:
if that doesn't work, try as it is done the link it is refered to see if that works

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

then use it like

```
new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
import { auth } from 'firebase';
```

Or:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

And then: `new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier`

Answer (score 0):

Change the import to:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

and then:

```
this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error throwed when i reloaded page. I use Ionic + Angular. So the problem could be in ngOnInit. The method calls it too early, and to solute this you can do:

1. Bring your recaptha to angular lifecycle hooks which goes last (AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked, or you could try with another hooks)

   `ngAfterContentChecked() { // recaptcha }`
2. For ionic i had page hook ionViewDidEnter

   `ionViewDidEnter() { // recaptcha }`
3. I can't place new RecaptchaVerifier with new `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');`

`window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');` - does'nt work like that

the right way:

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>

// ts
let recaptcha: any;
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
  this.recaptcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
}
```